# Not able to pass custom field value to Live Chat Transcript object usin embedded service chat extra Prechat JS

Tags: chat, pre-chat, embedded-services

I've below code in snippet setting file of embedded service chat component.

```
embedded_svc.snippetSettingsFile.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{
        label: "RecordTypeId",
        value: "012f4000000fP3tAAE",
        displayToAgent: false
    }, {
        "value": chatCookie.cvt,
        "transcriptFields":[ "cvt__c" ],
        "displayToAgent": false
    }, {
        "label" : "Contact Reason",
        "transcriptFields":[ "Contact_Reason__c" ],
        "displayToAgent": true
    }];
```

my **cvt__c** value sets to the LiveChatTranscript record as it has some specific value hardcoded(somehow) but for Contact Reason is configured in embedded service configuration with Contact object as a picklist, and whatever value is selected I want to pass it to LiveChatTranscript object's Text **Contact_Reason__c**.

It does work(pass the selected value) for English language as the label is **Contact Reason** but for any other (Spanish in my case) the label gets changed to **Motivo de contacto** and similarly to other languages I cannot put those label to pass dynamic value.

so conclusion in Contact Reason is not passed for non-English language.

please suggest what can be done here.